# Reason for changing floating values when saving Pandas dataframe to csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am trying to save a Pandas dataframe to a .csv file and I have tried with below code.

```
submission_df.head()
```

then I got the below result as my dataframe head.

[image]

Later, I used the below code to save the dataframe to a .csv file and looked for the head of my .csv file. The result was different from the above result.

```
submission_df.to_csv('/path/to/data/my_submission.csv', index=True)
!head my_submission.csv
```

Output:

```
respondent_id,h1n1_vaccine,seasonal_vaccine
26707,0.3068268366257748,0.5357696271429706
26708,0.05339661850925804,0.09507477609876568
26709,0.2570858695164222,0.741100787519942
26710,0.661774113692513,0.8678233487008229
26711,0.4957192566760516,0.6196195378487251
```

I need to know the reason for this behaviour. (However correct dataframe values have been saved to the .csv file and only the printed values are wrong)

Comment: What bothers me is that the value obtained from the database or the web page has two decimal places, and after saving to csv, some values ​​will be followed by a lot of 0

Answer (score 0):

I think you are reading a different file.Since you are storing your file in a `/path/to/data/`,you should read the file from this path.Try this

```
!head /path/to/data/my_submission.csv
```

Comment: That's not the reason dude. Before I add the `/path/to/data/`, it was just my_submission.csv

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV file is **correct** as it has saved the **real values** of your dataframe with much higher precision.

You may be confused with the output of your `submission_df.head()` command which (by default) displays **rounded** floating-point values (to **6** decimal places after the decimal point).

(Data types of values in your 2nd and 3rd column of your dataframe are  `float64`, which means about **16** significant digits in decimal form.)

You may change the default display with the command

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.16f}'.format
```

before applying your `submission_df.head()` command to see that numbers in your dataframe are the same as in your CSV output file.

---

*Note:*

You may reset changed display option for floating-point numbers back to default with command

```
pd.options.display.float_format = None
```

Comment: Now `submission_df.head( )` gives values with 16 digits but printed values are different.

Comment: This is simply impossible. Just after writing it to .csv try `df_other = pd.read_csv('/path/to/data/my_submission.csv')` and `df_other.head()`.